# Изучение HTML & CSS

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток!

На сайтах на основе вики-движка Wikimedia в разделе «Содержание» имеется пункт-ссылка «[убрать]»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу добавить эту штуку себе на сайт, код скопипастил, чего-то не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Тот самый код:

```
<nav id="toc" class="toc show">

    <div id="toctitle">
        <h2></h2>
        <span class="toctoggle">

            [

            <a id="togglelink" class="internal" data-hide="убрать" data-show="показать" href="#" title="убрать"></a>

            ]

        </span>
    </div>
    <ol></ol>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

ну поскольку я наверняка не дождусь что надо выложу свои соображения 
между тегами <head>

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script><script src="script.js"></script>
```

в корне сайта создаете script.js

в нем

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#togglelink.internal').live('click',function{
  jQuery(this).removeClass("internal");
  jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  var link = jQuery(this).attr("data-hide");
  jQuery(this).html(link);
  jQuery('селектор блока который надо расскрыть).addClass("activeDiv")
});
jQuery('#togglelink.active').live('click',function{
  jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
  jQuery(this).addClass("internal");
  var link = jQuery(this).attr("data-show");
  jQuery(this).html(link);
  jQuery('селектор блока который надо расскрыть').removeClass("activeDiv")
});
```

css

```
('селектор блока который надо расскрыть'){
  height:300px;}
('селектор блока который надо расскрыть').activeDiv{
  height:auto;}
```

это если раскрываемый блок блочный (div, p и т.д.) простите за тафтологию.

}

Comment: Спасибо дядя, помогло

Comment: Вам полный код надо, выложите html-код.     
Я вам подскажу.